# No instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have problem with `Intellisense` on `Visual Studio 2010`.

`Intellisense` doesn't suggest arguments for class constructors. Although it works fine with class methods.

```
class Window
{
    private:

        WindowImpl *Impl;

    public:

        static unsigned int WindowCount;

        Window();

        Window(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const std::string &title, int x, int y, unsigned int style);

        void Create(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const std::string &title, int x, int y, unsigned int style);

        ~Window();

        void Destroy();
};
```

Error: no instance of constructor matches the argument list

```
Window mainWindow(100, 200 ...
```

Works fine

```
mainWindow.Create(100, 200 ...
```

No compilation error, but `Intellisense` doesn't show (does not suggest) arguments for constructor and shows this error.

---

[image]

I figured out that problem exists with all classes. I hope screenshot will help understand what I mean. I have tried `Visual Assist X` and it doesn't help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: The question is how to fix this problem. How to make Intellisense work fine with class constructors. For example it works fine with std::string constructors, but not with my custrom classes.

Comment: It is not a problem of C++. It is a problem of visual studio.

Comment: It works here, but I don't have the 2010 version. Can anybody confirm that it just works? Or is this indeed a problem with VS2010?

Comment: @Nawaz That's what the OP said in the first sentence.

Comment: @MrLister: I didn't say OP is saying that. I am *telling him* that it is not a problem of C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your example in my VS 2010 and Intellisense is working fine for both lines. Note that if the function is overloaded, IntelliSense shows the first variant, and you can press up/down arrows to see other.
[image]

IntelliSense is known to get stuck sometimes, not indexing some classes or showing wrong results. In such a case you can close your project and delete intellisense database. When you reopen the project, it gets created from scratch, hopefully with more success.

Also if you are writing much C++ in VS, consider using Visual Assist X, which substitutes much of IntelliSense functionality, but performs much better. (I am not affiliated with Tomato Software, just in love with the tool.)

Comment: Now with your std::string screenshots I don't understand your problem at all ;( Have you tried rebuilding IntelliSense database?

Comment: How to rebuild IntelliSense database? I`ve deleted ipch folder and sdf file, but no changes at all. Anyway I will try to explain in more details. There are two ways to construct object. 1) MyClass object = MyClass(arguments); 2) MyClass object(arguments); So when I construct object with 1st method it works fine. But when I construct with 2nd method IntelliSense doesnt highlight arguments with bold (it should highlight 3rd argument, but highlight always only 1st argument). When I point my mouse to 1st argument I get error - no instance of constructor matches the argument list.

Comment: Got it. Right, I can reproduce your issue. Seems like a bug in IntelliSense, and given that IntelliSense doesn't have much configuration options, I'd write to Microsoft if I was you.
Or just forget, it's a very minor issue, isn't it?

Comment: Bug reported to Microsoft. Yes its not a big deal, but I would like it worked fine. Anyway thanks for help.